# How to get DLL to load during Add-Type execution?

Tags: powershell, dll, pinvoke

I am using P-Invoke to load a plain, C-style DLL in PowerShell. I see that the DLL is not loaded until the first DLL function is invoked.

The reason that I want the DLL to load when `$type` is created is because I believe that it leads to a better design and better code. It especially makes sense to load DLL up front when multiple threads are invoking DLL functions. I want the DLL to be loaded at a determined time, rather than at a nondeterministic time, depending on which thread gets to it first.

This code example shows what I am currently doing. `DllMain` does not print `process attached` until `MyDllFunction` is invoked.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $signature = @'
>> [DllImport("mylibrary.dll")]
>> public static extern void MyDllFunction();
>> '@
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Utils -Namespace GetPrivateProfileString -PassThru
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $type::MyDllFunction()
process attached
executing MyDllFunction
```

So, is there any way to load the DLL before the first function is invoked, rather than lazily at the first function invokation?

Comment: It looks like the behavior is incidental to PowerShell: `Add-Type` loads the _.NET_ types defined via `$signature`, but it seems that .NET's P/Invoke feature loads any referenced _native_ DLLs _lazily_, i.e. not until a method relying on that native DLL is actually _called_. _Conceivably_ you can use _reflection_ to inspect the dynamic assembly created by `Add-Type` in order to detect native-DLL references in it, but, assuming that it can be done, it will be a nontrivial effort.

Comment: *"it leads to a better design and better code."*. why? dll load time shouldn't be an issue, if the dll itself is properly coded, hence the .NET lazy load design. Otherwise call LoadLibrary using p/invoke https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw and FreeLibrary (you'll have to pair these calls by yourself)